# encrypt binary with 7z without filenames?

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I am wondering, i like 7z compression but how do i compress data only? i dont want a file in the archive with file info. Just raw data, how can i do this? it would also be nice if i can remove headers too but that isnt necessary.

Answer (score 3):

From [`man 7z`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/7z):

> `-si    Read data from StdIn (eg: tar cf - directory | 7z a -si directory.tar.7z)`