# Can i put binary in stdin? C#

Tags: c#, .net, stream, stdin

Related to this question [encrypt binary with 7z without filenames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284088/encrypt-binary-with-7z-without-filenames/1284101#1284101)

In C# how can i put binary in STDin? i was hoping the below would work but it doesnt. And it makes sense. So how do i push a byte[] array?

```
new BinaryWriter(p.StandardInput.FormatProvider);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Write directly to the base stream:

```
new BinaryWriter(p.StandardInput.BaseStream)
```

Comment: Or use `p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write`.

Answer (score 3):

`stdin` is just another byte stream, one your program can read from

```
Stream st=Console.OpenStandardInput ();
StreamReader sr=new StreamReader(st);
```

etc.  In the q. which you refer to, the material coming in from `stdin` is being piped from the output of another program.  To do that part of the process, you use `Console.OpenStandardOuput()` to get a stream and push the binary out through that.

Comment: Yes, but if you're dealing with binary, you don't want to use `StreamReader`, which is derived from `TextReader`.

Comment: Yes -- should be BinaryReader.

Comment: Well, maybe or maybe not. If you just want to deal with bytes, then dealing with the raw stream is fine. Other things like the `BinaryFormatter` will also be useful - just not a `TextReader`.