# Redirecting stdin and stdout where stdin closes first

Tags: c#, ipc

This is actually related to another question I had that was already answered.  That question is here: [Redirecting stdout of one process object to stdin of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349543/redirecting-stdout-of-one-process-object-to-stdin-of-another)

My issue is (I think) that the program who is getting the input should exit before the program outputting.  Here is the bash equivalent of what I'm doing: tccat -i /dev/sr0 -T 1 | ffmpeg -i - -r 1 -t 1 -s 96x72 -ss 5 /tmp/wsmanage/preview_tmp/test\%03d.jpg

This just uses a program called tccat to read the first title of a dvd.  That gets output to ffmpeg, which is going to create an output file at 1 frame per second that is 1 second long in .jpg format.  As soon as it outputs its frame (or two) it exists.  This works fine.

The following code, however, does not.  I get scads of "Printing line to ffmpeg", whereas the command line version exits in just over a second.  Then, it just stops printing after 30 or 40 seconds or so.  FFmpeg never exits, and my program never continues.

I'm I doing this right?

```
Process tccatProcess = new Process();           
tccatProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "tccat";
tccatProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-i {0} -T {1}", devNode, title);
tccatProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
tccatProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process ffmpegProcess = new Process();
string bashSafePreviewTemplate = slasher.bashSlash(previewTempDir + "/test%03d.jpg");
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-i - -r 1 -t 1 -s {1}x{2} -ss {3} {0}", 
    bashSafePreviewTemplate, width, height, timePosition);
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;


try{
    tccatProcess.Start();
    ffmpegProcess.Start();

    StreamReader tccatOutput = tccatProcess.StandardOutput;
    StreamWriter ffmpegInput = ffmpegProcess.StandardInput;

    string line;
    while(!ffmpegProcess.HasExited)
    {
        ffmpegProcess.Refresh();
        if((line = tccatOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Printing line to ffmpeg");
            Console.Out.Flush();
            ffmpegInput.WriteLine(line);
            ffmpegInput.Flush();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Closing tccat");
    Console.Out.Flush();
    tccatProcess.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Tccat closed");
    Console.Out.Flush();


}catch(Exception e){
    //uninteresting log code
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't tccat output binary data since you're working with video and images? If so shouldn't you be reading/writing to the input/output streams directly rather than wrapping them in a text reader?

If so you want to be using [Can i put binary in stdin? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284184/can-i-put-binary-in-stdin-c/1284753#1284753)

Comment: Ah, this may be my problem.  I didn't realize that streamreader/streamwriter were not binary safe.  I'll try this as soon as I can and post back with the results!  Thanks for the link also.  I see just what I need to do.  Even if this isn't my only problem, I can see it's definitly something that needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who wants to do something similar, here is the new version with KeeperOfTheSoul's advice applied:

```
        Process tccatProcess = new Process();           
        tccatProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "tccat";
        tccatProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-i {0} -T {1}", devNode, title);
        tccatProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        tccatProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        Process ffmpegProcess = new Process();
        string bashSafePreviewTemplate = slasher.bashSlash(previewTempDir + "/test%03d.jpg");
        ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
        ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("-i - -r 1 -t 1 -s {1}x{2} -ss {3} {0}", 
            bashSafePreviewTemplate, width, height, timePosition);
        ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        Console.WriteLine("tccat command: {0} {1}", tccatProcess.StartInfo.FileName, tccatProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);
        Console.WriteLine("ffmpeg command: {0} {1}", ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.FileName, ffmpegProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);

        //return true;

        try{
            tccatProcess.Start();
            ffmpegProcess.Start();

            BinaryReader tccatOutput = new BinaryReader(tccatProcess.StandardOutput.BaseStream);
            BinaryWriter ffmpegInput = new BinaryWriter(ffmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream);
            int buffSize = 4096;
            byte[] buff = new byte[buffSize];


            while(!ffmpegProcess.HasExited)
            {
                ffmpegProcess.Refresh();
                buff = tccatOutput.ReadBytes(buffSize);
                ffmpegInput.Write(buff);
                ffmpegInput.Flush();
            }


            tccatProcess.Kill();
            tccatProcess.Close();
            ffmpegProcess.Close();


        }catch(Exception e){
                    //uninteresting log code
                    return false;

        }
```