# How to write to the stdin of another app?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

I have a module that reads the StandardError of a process. Everything works fine, but I want to do something different. I don't know how to redirect stdin like the native way:

`app1.exe -someargs | app2.exe -someargs`

Where app2 reads all the stdout of app1 in its stdin.

Comment: This answer should give you a good idea [C# Console receive input with pipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199528/c-console-receive-input-with-pipe)

Comment: But the second application is not written by me. I need to send bytes to subprocess, not receive them.

Comment: @blez, it should be pretty obvious. Writing is the opposite of reading. Where the linked answer tells you to read from the Console, you Write to the Console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the MSDN reference documentation for the following (both to be found in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace):

- [`Process.StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx)
- [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx). 
  There's an example showing how to start a child process and write directly to its standard input.

**For your particular example, here's how you set things up:**

1. *app1* starts *app2* as a child process using the `Process` class (see links above).
2. *app1* writes to *app2*'s standard input by writing to the `.StandardInput` stream of the `Process` object associated with *app2*.
3. *app2* just reads lines from its standard input (e.g. via `Console.ReadLine()`).

Answer (score 9):

Once you have the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) object representing the process you want to communicate with (either because you got it from the OS using the static method [`Process.GetProcesses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses.aspx), or because you created it yourself), you can attach a [`StreamWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) to the [`Process.StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) property and use that to write to the stdin of the process. Don't forget to set [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput.aspx) on your newly created process to `true`.

On a related note, you can use a [`StreamReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) on the [`Process.StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) to read the output (like reading from `StandardError`).

Answer (score 1):

I had to use BinaryWriter, this article explains all:
[BinaryWriter and StdIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373387/redirecting-stdin-and-stdout-where-stdin-closes-first)